# Should I use variables or user settings?

Tags: c#, settings.settings, settings

I have a program which has a few important variables. Essentially, these integers will be changing frequently (less than every second potentially for some). but all at different rates.

I need them to all be saved between runs of the program, so will of course be storing them as user settings. My problem though, I don't know which would be better. I don't know how often to call the save() method first off, but I am thinking every ten seconds?

With that in mind, do I perform all my work on these integers as variables, and continually copy the values across to user settings? or should I work directly from the settings, modifying them directly and just hitting that save() method?

To add an example....

Lets say I have 10 setting in settings.settings which are going to have a lot of use. set01 - set10 for now.

I will be constantly editing these values, and saving them roughly every ten seconds.

When I am incrementing the values, should I take option a:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.set01 += 500;
Properties.Settings.Default.set02 += 400;
...
```

^ Working with them in such a way where they could all update several times across ten seconds, and then just hit

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

every ten seconds... OR...

Should I take values from the settings:

```
int set01 = Properties.Settings.Default.set01;    
set01 += 500;
```

then repeat actions like that across the ten seconds... and then:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.set01 = set01;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Essentially... It would be easier to work straight with the settings, but would there be a drawback to doing this? Would it be technically incorrect to do so etc? Would performance suffer noticeably?

Comment: can you show some code in regards to what you already have so that it supports your current question at hand

Comment: If you are confident that program will never quit without saving these variables, there is no harm in keeping it in memory and save every ten second. That ways, you can even save it in background.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, what a beautiful day for Yak Shaving!

I would recommend that you create and use a central object which exposes these variables as properties, so all your code base makes use of the properties of that object. (Also, I would ***not*** make this object a global variable, I would make sure to explicitly pass it to every place that really needs it, but that's just me.)

Then, you can choose how to implement these properties: either have them cache the values in member variables and only save rarely, or to always load and save.

Now, initially, you will, of course, provide the easiest implementation, which would be to have each getter load the user setting on the spot, and each setter save the user setting on the spot, *with complete disregard towards performance*. So, my recommendation would be to code them like this and forget about them until the product is completed and almost ready to ship.

Then, right before shipping, use a profiler to see whether all this saving represents any significant overhead at all, and if so, then *and only then* go optimize that spot.  My guess: you will not need to, or have to.  Other concerns will take precedence.

Any course of action which deviates from the above is [Yak Shaving](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YakShavingDefinedIllGetThatDoneAsSoonAsIShaveThisYak.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing a performance impact with the config file, you can just use the registry.  The registry is orders of magnitude faster for repeated reads and writes, and has the same persistence guarantees.

The registry requires no separate Save call, and could absolutely be updated on each `set`, and read on each `get`.  You would, of course, keep the key open for the lifetime of the application.  A wrapper class would be advisable to hide the actual persistence from calling code.

```
// pseudo code, since I don't have MSDN open right now...
using (var regKey = RegistryHive.CurrentUser.OpenKey("Software\\MyApp"))
{
    int myValue = (int)regKey.GetValue("foo", RegKeyValueType.Dword, /* default: */ 0);
    return myValue;
}
```

I will also note that frequent writes to a .net config file increases the probability of a corrupt file.  Unless handled explicitly, a corrupt config file will cause a hard crash on opening the application on .Net 2.  I am not certain about higher versions, but we get 3-4 calls where users cannot open an application because the computer lost power during a write, or someone killed the process at the perfect time.

I am similarly uncertain as to how .Net handles sharing violations on Save, but I would guess it just throws an `IOException`.  Running multiple copies of the application may be complicated if the config file is written to simultaneously.